# ggplot 2d contour plot doesn't cover my data

Tags: r, contour, density-plot

I'm trying to make a contour plot for the bivariate distribution for two parameters lambda and nu, however the contour lines don't seem to cover my data points. I was wondering if there is anyway to increase the number of lines to cover the entire range?

```r
ggplot(cbind.data.frame(lambda1, v1), aes(x = lambda1, y = v1)) +
       geom_point(data = cbind.data.frame(lambda1, v1),
                  aes(x = lambda1, y = v1), 
                  color = "grey",
                  alpha = 1/10,
                  shape = 1) +
       geom_density_2d(size=0.5) +
       xlab("Lambda") +
       ylab("nu")
```

[image: Contour plot]

Comment: Have you tried the ```bins = ....``` argument, e.g. ```geom_density_2d(bins = 30)``` - see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_contour.html for reference

Comment: Yes, that's worked, such a simple solution, I can't believe I overlooked that, thanks!